# Spelling of name

Tags: перевод

Just out of curiosity, I was given the name Юля that I was to map in to IPA. When I tried to look up "Юля" it came up as "Юлия". As Russian speaker what is the difference between these two spellings and are these two, two different names?

I would love to hear your input on this and if they are referring to the same name what is the background. What is commonly used in Russian language today?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the same name.
`Юля` is just a shorthand for the name `Юлия`.
So, the difference is the same as between, for example, `Mike` and `Michael`.